# Is it bad for my dog to drink soapy shower water (that is all he drinks)

Tags: dogs, drinking

My dog refuses to drink clean cool water from a bowl. He comes into the shower when I am showering and drinks the soapy water. I have tried all shapes and colours of drinking dishes and bowls, but he insists on drinking from the shower. Will this be detrimental to his health?

Comment: Have you tried putting a tiny drop off milk into the bowl's water? Does this change anything?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that your dogs only source of fluids (water) is from when you shower.  If he is not drinking from a dog bowl is it possible he is drinking from the [toilet?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1394)

Answer (score 4):

Never let your pets drink soapy water, as some soaps are laxatives and can upset their digestive systems. Lock the door when you bathe.

If your dog refuses to drink from regular water bowls, perhaps she doesn't like it because it hits her whiskers, and the sensation is unpleasant. Perhaps try a wider bowl, if you haven't already.

Dehydration is a possibility if she's truly not drinking, but most dogs WILL drink when they get thirsty enough, regardless of previous reservations.

If a wider bowl doesn't work, switch tactics entirely and invest in a fountain-type water dispenser. Speak with one of the clerks at Petsmart or wherever you buy your pet products -- who knows, they may have experience with sensitive dogs.

Comment: Mariah/riah if you would prefer to be identified as Mariah, you can edit your profile so your display name will be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

When my dog isn't drinking enough (he has crystals in his urine and I want him to drink more) I put some kibble in his water bowl - just a little so he is forced to drink it while 'fishing' for the kibble. Kind of like apple bobbing.

I've also tried adding water to the food but then I think it gets too mushy and he tends to get kibble paste stuck in his teeth more.